# Summing a parsed field in Grafana Loki

Tags: grafana-loki

I am trying to sum the count of rows (row_count) being inserted/updated according to my process logs, which look similar to the following line:

```
{"function": "Data Processing Insert", "module": "Data Processor", "environment": "DEV", "level": "INFO", "message": "Number of rows inserted", "time": "2022-04-29T09:07:02.735Z", "epoch_time": 1651223222.735133, "row_count": "8089"}
```

I'm able to build the filter to get those lines but haven't been able to perform calculations on row_count.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grafana community channel came thru.  To do what I'm looking for I had to use unwrap:

```
sum_over_time({__aws_cloudwatch_log_group="/aws/batch/job"} | json | message=~".+inserted" | unwrap row_count [1h])
```